# How to do Pull Origin in GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I just updated my GitHub Desktop version from 3.3.6.1 to the latest. I was able to update my remote branch by using Fetch origin but I don't see Pull Origin button to update my local branch.

[image]

Not sure how to get it. I did some research but wasn't able to find out the Pull Origin button.

Thanks

Comment: A pull is a fetch and then a merge. Click the fetch origin button?

Comment: I am aware of that but it never updates the local repo and this is what all I am asking

Comment: It might be that there’s nothing to update? Try confirming using the command line.

Comment: There is an update. I've checked the merge request and my local is not getting updated by just pressing the fetch origin.

Comment: Have you confirmed this on the command line? Maybe there’s an error which github desktop isn’t reporting?

Comment: My fellow Developer has merged his changes, it is confirmed that there is a change and I need to update my local repo. In prior versions it used to say update from now in the latest version there should be pull origin to update my local repo.

Comment: It’s not that I don’t trust your fellow developer, but could you try these things in the command line and see what the result is?

Comment: I guess the problem was with the UI, not sure what and why. I reinstalled it and created a local repo and after fetch origin i was able to get the Pull origin to update my local repo. Thank you for following up on this.

Comment: Fab. Consider answering the question with your solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having troubles understanding how `Fetch origin` works on GitHub Desktop, but eventually figured out that the origin here is the fork.

To fetch and merge changes from the remote, one should update the `Primary remote repository (origin)` field on `Repository` -> `Repository settings` with the remote's link.

[image]

At this stage, the `Fetch origin` works as expected and shows the `Pull origin` button to merge the changes from the remote into one's fork.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Version:3.16.3
Actually I had previously added command in additional args in my old flutter/dart version to avoid null safety in my vs code settings,that was working fine. but after upgrade my flutter now. I had to remove them , and it started working fine.
[image]